# How to Send Message and Status by result WebApi Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to return Message and Status Code in ***WebAPI Core 3.1***.
For Example Service **GetAllUsers()** return AllUser and return code is `OK(Users)`.
it's OK.

But if **GetAllUsers()** return null (User Not Fund),Service return **204 Status Code**.
204 Code No body.How to Send Message by 204?
If I have to use 404 instead of 204. So what is the reason for 204?

Another issue:

In **500 statusCode** we have the output as follows:

```
  {
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1",
    "title": "An error occured while processing your request.",
    "status": 500,
    "detail": "Error",
    "traceId": "|b8dbff20-4a070d9818356f4c."
  }
```

And for other codes in a different way. Is there a way to create a class for all codes and have a single output?I need this class for Android programmers.
I just need a message that might be a JSON list and I have a status.
We used to do this with Jason before, but now everybody has a comment.

Comment: 204 is the equivalent of NoContent() and is designed to return no content on purpose.  Sounds like you should be returning NotFound() which is a 404.

Comment: You also asked "What's the purpose of 204?" - it's often used after adding a new item (PUT/POST) where the standard practice is to either return the entire collection of objects or, because returning everything is not normally required, you can return a NoContent() (e.g. the item was added as requested but you won't get the full collection back)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to send a message with a 200 status even if the result is empty you can try this:

```
var result = GetAllUsers();
if(!result) return Ok("no available users");
else {
return Ok(result);
}
```

If you still want to send a 200 status code with an empty body you can try this:

```
var result = GetAllUsers();
if(!result) return Ok(); // will return an empty body with a 200 code
else {
return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause problems to the users of the API when deserializing the response? They would expect that the HTTP 200 Response matches a specific structure of an object.

Comment: You are right, that is why the best practice is to return a 204 status code. If you still want to return a 200 response with an empty body you can check the new code that i added.